# Including View blocks into a view page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I include view blocks into a view page? Let's say I have two view blocks named "promoted_feed" and "sliding_feed" and I want those included in /frontpage view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [views_field_view](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) is what you need?

Comment: Nice. I ended up using a different approach yesterday, but this seems nice.

Answer (score 2):

From UI: Each views block created are listed under admin->structure->blocks by the block name you assigned it to, when you created the view. To make the views block be rendered into a page (any valid drupal url), go to structure->blocks, find the block, click configure. On the configuration page, scroll all the way down to Visibility settings -> pages -> only the listed pages, list the path(relative, no leading '/') for view page and save.